# Modifying whitelisted property on Spring cloud Data Flow UI

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am able to whitelist properties in a task using spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties. The properties whitelisted is displayed in read only mode on the application detail screen.

Even on the task creation or detail screen the whitelisted properties are not shown in order to override the default value. Is there any way to change the whitelisted property value using the spring cloud dataflow screen?

Comment: I figured it out how to achieve it in UI. While creating the task definition (create tasks), specify the property next to the task definition name with its value in the visual editor text area of the create task screen. Eg:- TEST --job.config-file=file:spring_v02.xml. Where TEST is the name of the task app and job.config-file is the whitelisted property that I want to override.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the properties of Stream/Task applications when building the data pipeline from the GUI.

You'd click the application that requires the change and then select the "gear" icon (see attached pic) to go about changing the properties. Alternatively, you can manually provide the k/v pairs *(e.g.: `--job.config-file=file:spring_v02.xml`)* that'd like to override on the textual DSL section on the top section to the drag-and-drop canvas.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sabby. Didnt know the UI has that feature. This is more user friendly and help us a lot.

Comment: We will document it with a screenshot. Also, we will revisit how it can be made easier to discover from within the GUI. Thank you for the feedback!